# product set a column unique without being the primary key

Tags: sql, db2

I wanna create the following table:

```
create table product (id bigint not null, product_type varchar(50), product_name varchar(100), available_from TIMESTAMP, available_to TIMESTAMP, primary key (id));
```

My table's key is the 'id'.

when inserting in the table, I wanna that the product_type be unique.

How to do that without setting the product_type the key for my table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE <your table name>
 ADD CONSTRAINT unique_product_type UNIQUE(product_type);
```

I can't see a table name in your create table SQL.

Comment: I added the table's name :)

Answer (score 0):

The function NEWID() generates a new unique id. Maybe you can make a trigger which insets this in every insert or make the default value to be NEWID(). Well the second option seems a bit better :P

```
CREATE TABLE Test123
(
    ID NVARCHAR(200) DEFAULT (NEWID()),
    name NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO Test123 (name) VALUES ('test')

SELECT * FROM Test123

DROP TABLE Test123
```

Comment: AFAIK NEWID() is a mssql function, regardless of that I don't see how your answer relates to the question

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique constraint, something like this (not tested):

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    product_type varchar(50),
    product_name varchar(100),
    available_from TIMESTAMP,
    available_to TIMESTAMP,
    primary key (id),
    UNIQUE (product_type)
)
```